# SQL Query : how copy all tags of post into their post content in wordpress by sql query

Tags: query, tags, sql, content

I want to copy/move all tags of a post into posts content, as text form not in a link form.

For example:

> A post has:
>
> - a title in title field,
> - some content in content field (like: a boy has good nature),
> - three tags (like: x1,x2,x3).

Can we copy all tags of that post in their content field, like:

> A post has:
>
> - a title in title field,
> - some content in content field (like: a boy has good nature x1 x2 x3),
> - three tags (like: x1,x2,x3).

as in text, not in link form.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply preprocess the content by adding a filter to `the_content` like that:

```
function wpse_337486( $content ) {

    if ( is_single() ) {

        // Get the current post.
        global $post;

        // Get all post tags. Get only their names.
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID, ['fields' => 'names']);

        // Append post tags to content.
        $content = $content . ' ' . implode(' ', $tags);
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_337486' );
```

Comment: no, actually i want: SQL Query : how copy all tags of post into their post content in wordpress by sql query

Comment: kindly, do by sql query, to changes data in the_content of post, by all tags of post, thanks

Comment: @NeerajBill – Why? Why SQL? What exactly is the root cause why you want to do it with SQL?

Comment: because want to use this in search

Comment: @NeerajBill – Sounds you should simply hook into the post save action. As you don't want to run the SQL query every month or so again to update all new posts manually.

Comment: that great for me, but how do this, can u give code, i am waiting, this is very important for me

Comment: @NeerajBill – Or maybe better create a custom Gutenberg block and let the editors place the tags that way?!